# Threading and Progressbar in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, gps, onresume

Hey guys so I'm trying to display gps distance between the user and some place on a card they can see. The problem is, I think the main thread splits or does 2 things at once. At the code below, Android makes a toast while doing the code in the if(flag) statement... so it toasts the GPS difference without getting the coordinates of the user...How do i make it so that, it does if(flag) statement first then goes on to do the toast after and outside the if statement?

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    ImagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
    if(ImagePath == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"hello everyone",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(newCardAdded)
    {
        flag = displayGpsStatus();
        if(flag)
        {
            editLocation.setText("Please!! move your device to" +
                    " see the changes in coordinates." + "\nWait..");
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();//LocationListener actually physically gets your location
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);


        }
        else
        {
            alertbox("Gps Status!!", "Your GPS is: OFF");
        }
            Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().getlatitude = place_lat;
            Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().getlongitutde = place_lon;
            String gps_distance = String.valueOf(gps_difference(user_lon, user_lat,place_lon,place_lat));
            Toast.makeText(this, gps_distance, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: If the toast that's supposed to display gps_distance isn't working properly, what is it displaying?  How do you know that it's occuring in the middle of the `if(flag)` statement block?

Comment: So in another activity I grab the GPS coordinates of a restaurant, and I want to toast the distance between the users location (whcih i get in this activity) and the restaurant's location (in another activity). So it just toasts the restaurants location at the same time a progress bar is running trying to retrieve the users location.

Answer (score 1):

[LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

Your `locationListener` must implement `onLocationChanged(Location)` method, which will be called for each location update. Then calculate distance and make a toast in that method. Because `requestLocationUpdates(...)` runs in another thread, there's no way to confirm that it is done before `Toast.makeText(...)`, so you must use your `MyLocationListener`.

Comment: is that the only way to do it? Do I have to make a toast in onLocationChanged? Is there a way to make it one thread or make sure requestLocationUpdates doesnt go on another thread?

Comment: do you think if i put a boolean statement (call it "gps_check" and initially set it to false) then in the onLocationChanged set that bool statement to true. Then, make a later if statement that checks if gps_check is true then do the toast?

Comment: No you can't do that. Because you don't know when `gps_check` is true. You don't know your `if` statement run before or after `gps_check` is set. Using `onLocationChanged()` is the right way, that's call a "callback".

Comment: Actually `requestLocationUpdates` runs on main thread, and it is just a fast "request" to android that you want to know when user's location is changed. After that, some internal methods in will be called, and you can't modify them, so there's nothing to do with combining threads.

Comment: man, that really blows. Yeah I was just trying to find a way to work around it. But thanks man.